# Office Communicator copy/paste removes most formatting

Tags: office-communicator-2007

When I copy/paste code from Visual Studio to a communicator window, it looks like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Any ideas why? It wasn't always like this.

Comment: If you posted the same code into Word or Outlook it would do something similar.  There is a reason for that Visual Studio doesn't use the same engine as Word, Outlook, or even Office Communicator does.

Comment: Word and Outlook work fine